# Why php will trim the first character from temporary file which produced by shell substitution?

Tags: php, shell

Shell has a very useful function called `process substitution`

```
$ cat <(echo '<?php echo "abc";')
<?php echo "abc";

$ echo <(echo '<?php echo "abc";')
/dev/fd/17
```

It seems that php will trim the first character from temporary file: `/dev/fd/17`

```
$ php <(echo '<?php echo "abc";')
?php echo "abc";

$ php <(echo ' <?php echo "abc";')
abc
```

So, why php will trim the first character from temporary file which produced by shell substitution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant this:

```
php < <(echo '<?php echo "abc\n"; ?>')
abc
```

Or you can use pipes:

```
echo '<?php echo "abc\n"; ?>' | php
abc
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. My question is about php with `shell's process substitution`, not php with `pipe`/`stdin`

Comment: First command I showed above is actually using **process substitution**.

Comment: Yes, in your first example, you redirected `process substitution`'s output to *stdin* of  `php` via redirect operator `<`. 
Henc, php will read *text stream* from `stdin` directly. It's no problem.

But my example in question has no redirect operator `<`. It has a *trim* problem as I said above. That's a different problem, even though both of them using `process substitution`.

Comment: Yes that's right. `php <(echo '<<?php echo "abc\n"; ?>')` works but needs an extra `<` before `<?php`